# Force.com IDE for Eclipse not showing all apex classes and pages

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse with the Force.com IDE and after I did a "refresh from server" on the src folder, I noticed that I could no longer edit a good many of my apex classes and pages. The packages.xml file is only showing a small portion of the classes that are actually associated with the SalesForce.com instance.

I have no clue what to do. Help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right click on your project folder -> Hover over the "Force.com" menu -> Select Add/Remove Metadata Components -> Click on the Add/Remove button -> Click the "Refresh" Icon, then uncheck and recheck the folders you want in your project.

Comment: This is a workaround for a bug, right? Or is this the intended behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Is the class or page that you are looking for, a part of the package.xml file?

Can you add the class / page names in the package.xml and refresh it again? Or you can also try to extract ALL the classes / pages by using the '*' in the package.xml file.

```
<types>
<member>*</member>
<name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
```